# java read character by System.in

Tags: java, character

this is my code, the problem I have is that if I enter a word of more than one character I will not be asked again for a word of one character.

```
public static String datoStringChar() {
    //EN casa de introducir mas de una letra coje la primera
    // Entorno:
    InputStreamReader br;

    char letra;
    boolean esCorrecto;
    //Algoritmo
    letra = '0';
    br = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    try {
        do {
            letra = (char) br.read();
            esCorrecto = true;
        } while (!esCorrecto);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Error I/O");

    }
    return Character.toString(letra);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any prompt at all.

Comment: Why should your porgram read multiple characters? within your loop, you read one character and set the loop-condtion variable `esCorrecto` to `true`, exiting the loop. If you want to keep looping, you need to change your loop-condition.

Comment: por que no estas chequeando si le letra q acabas de ingresar es igual a la letra `letra = 0`. Solo dices `esCorrecto = true` despues del primer ciclo. Tienes q tener otro variable q se llama algo como `nuevaLetra=(char) br.read();` y tienes q chequear si `if (nuevaLetra == letra) { esCorrecto = true}`.  Si no, no pongas el valor `true` en el variable `esCorrecto`. Asi el programa va repitiendo y pidiendo q ingreses una letra hasta q la letra q ingreses sea igual a la letra q tienes en el variable `letra`

Comment: @JabariDash Hola, gracias por responder, pero eso sería si lo que quieres que solo una letra sea leida, pero no me habré expresado muy bien seguramente, ruego que me disculpes por esto, queria pedir, que  si ingresas "hola", te lo rechace, ya que este programa slo coge la "h" y lo convierte en un char, pero lo que quiero  que haga es que solo te deje meter un caracter, a-zA-Z 0-9 o cualquier otro del codigo ascii